# Clojure libraries lacking (so use Java)...?

Tags: java, clojure

From Clojure it is easy enough to use Java libraries...but what libraries does Clojure not have that are best done with Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't easy to give a straightforward question to this answer, because it would be first necessary to define the difference between a *Clojure library* and a *Java library*. (Even more so, because Clojure is a Java library :))

Ok, let's start with a premise that a Clojure library is any library written in Clojure and simply ignore the Java code in Clojure implementation itself. But, what if given library uses some Java dependency, like say one of Apache Commons libraries? Would it still qualify as a Clojure and not Java library?

My own criterion (and I am guessing yours, too) for the difference between the two is whether or not the library exposes a Clojure-style interface with namespaces, functions, sequences or a Java-style interface with classes, methods and collections.

It is almost trivial to write Clojure wrappers around such Java libraries. In my experience that is very useful if you want to fit in functionality of the library in overall functional design of your application. A simple example would be if you want to `map` a Java method against a sequence. You can either use an ad-hoc defined anonymous function to wrap the method call, or a named function from your wrapper layer. If you do such things very often the second approach may be more suited, at least for most commonly used methods.

**So, my conclusion is that any Java library should be easy to *convert* to a Clojure library. All that is needed is to write a wrapper for it.**

Another conclusion is that it may not be needed at all. If all you want is to call the method, you may still just call the method and avoid all the architecture astronautics. :)

Comment: I agree with the architecture astronaut comment. I believe there is little value in "re-abstracting" Java APIs into Clojure APIs. This is a trap that many novice Clojure programmers fall into busily writing wrapper APIs. I fell into this trap myself when first learning Clojure. In general, it is best to simply use Clojure Java interop although you may wish to wrap certain Java calls into functions to avoid code repetition and duplication in ad-hoc fashion.

Comment: @Julien: In my opinion, it really depends in each particular case. For example, I wrote a Clojure wrapper for my own small Java library. Apart from using functions instead methods, other gains were functions instead of Java callback objects and conversion from Java collections to Clojure persistent data structures. I think it was well worth the effort in that case. Of course, for larger and/or simpler APIs writing a wrapper could be somewhere between cumbersome and utterly useless. As with most decisions, the question is if benefit is worth the cost.

Answer (score 1):

One potential answer may be a bytecode library like ASM http://asm.ow2.org/

But honestly, with time, any library in Java can be written in clojure. Some Java code that compiled to different bytecode can be replicated if clojure uses ASM underneath.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly prefer Clojure as a language for development in general, but there are several good reasons I have found for using Java libraries or writing Java code in preference to Clojure:

- **Leveraging mature Java libraries** - some Java libraries are truly excellent and very mature. From a pragmatic perspective, you are much better off directly using Java libraries like Netty, Swing or Joda Time rather than trying to utilise or invent some Clojure alternative. Sometimes there are Clojure wrappers for these libraries but these are mostly still in a somewhat experimental / immature state.
- **High performance code** - I do quite a lot of data and image processing where maximum performance in essential. This rules out pretty much any approach that adds overhead (such as lazy sequences, temporary object creation) so idiomatic Clojure won't fit the bill. You could probably get there with very unidiomatic Clojure (lots of tight imperative loops and primitive array manipulation for example...) but if you're going to write this kind of code it's often actually simpler and cleaner in Java
- **APIs with mutable semantics** - if the APIs you are relying upon depend upon mutable objects, Clojure code to interface with these APIs can become a bit ugly and unidiomatic. Sometimes writing Java in these cases is simpler.

The good news is that because the interoperability between Clojure and Java is so good, there isn't really any issue with mixing Clojure and Java code in a project. As a result, most of my projects are a mix of Clojure and Java code - I use whichever one is most appropriate for the task at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries for building GUIs comes to mind.

Comment: What? You can use Swing with Clojure. There are no Java libraries that are not actually accessible from Clojure.

Comment: seesaw is nice UI library for desktop applications.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of APIs. In fact, Clojure itself is built on top many sturdy Java APIs like the java.util.Collection API. And well known Clojure APIs like Incanter are built on top of libraries like Parallel Colt, and JFreeChart.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the quote at the moment; but Rich said somthing to the effect of "clojure should use java where possible" and not wrap java unnecessarily. The principal being to embrace the java platform instead of fighting it. so the general advice becomes:

If a good java library exists use it, if not write one in clojure.